# How do I set different signup forms for the same MailChimp list?

Tags: forms, list, mailchimp

I need to set different signup forms for the same MailChimp list. For example:

- A signup form with just Name and E-mail.
- A signup form with just Name, E-mail, City and Company.
- A complete signup form with all fields available.

These different signup forms would be applied on different circumstances, but they would all register the subscriber on the same list.

Please let me know when this will be implemented.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you goto Form Builder in Mailchimp choose Embedded forms.

When in here choose the 'Naked' option.

This provides you the raw html that you can then amend. Eg. I removed the first name and last name and fields that came with it.

Be aware that if you have any required fields, you will not be able to submit form without them included. There is a link to the form editor which let's you choose which fields are required.

Comment: Good idea. You can easily tweak the required fields if necessary